# Can cflow in aspectJ detect cross-thread execution?

Tags: java, multithreading, aspectj

**Problem**

I want to print out the request url and response before running all calls to method

```
public class UpdateRequester {
   private void throwMessage(String requestUrl, String page) {
      //Some code inside
   }
}
```

the method will be called is in the Test class:

```
public class Test {
  public void testUpdate() {
    Executors.scheduleWithFixedDelay(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
          //It will call throwMessage sometimes in the future
        }
    }, ...);
  }  
}
```

so I designed an aspect:

```
public aspect TestUpdate {
   static final void println(String s) {
     System.out.println(s);
   }

   pointcut testUpdateFlow() : cflow(this(Test) && execution(void testUpdate()));

   pointcut throwMessageCut(String url, String response) : this(UpdateRequester) && args(url, response) && execution(void throwMessage(String, String));

   before(String url, String response) : testUpdateFlow() && throwMessageCut( url,  response) {
    println("=============Url============");
    println(url);
    println("============Respnse=========");
    println(response);
   }
}
```

The aspect doesn't print anything to the console. If I remove testUpdateFlow(), it did print to the console. 
I think that cflow in aspectJ doesn't consider the code running by `Executors.scheduleWithFixedDelay` to be in the flow of `testUpdate()`. Is there any way I can use for aspectJ to detect thread-crossing call in this situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us assume we have these classes:

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

public class UpdateRequester {
    public void doSomething() {
        throwMessage("http://my.url.org/foo", "my page");
    }

    private void throwMessage(String requestUrl, String page) {
        System.out.println("Throwing message for request " + requestUrl + " on page '" + page + "'");
    }
}
```

Because `throwMessage(..)` is private in your example, I deliberately added a public method `doSomething()` which can be called by the test class to which I also added a `main(..)` method as an entry point for my test:

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class Test {
    public void testUpdate() {
        ScheduledExecutorService executorService = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(10);
        executorService.scheduleWithFixedDelay(
            new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    new UpdateRequester().doSomething();
                }
            },
            500L,
            1000L,
            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS
        );
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test().testUpdate();
    }
}
```

Now let us print an exception stack trace from our `before()` advice in order to find out what the control flow really is:

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

import de.scrum_master.app.UpdateRequester;

public aspect TestUpdate {
    pointcut throwMessageCut(String url, String response) :
        this(UpdateRequester) &&
        args(url, response) &&
        execution(void throwMessage(String, String));

    before(String url, String response) :
        /*testUpdateFlow() &&*/
        throwMessageCut(url,  response)
    {
        System.out.println(thisJoinPoint);
        new Exception().printStackTrace(System.out);
    }
}
```

You see a stack trace like this:

```
execution(void de.scrum_master.app.UpdateRequester.throwMessage(String, String))
java.lang.Exception
    at de.scrum_master.app.TestUpdate.ajc$before$de_scrum_master_app_TestUpdate$1$33fbc0c(TestUpdate.aj:16)
    at de.scrum_master.app.UpdateRequester.throwMessage(UpdateRequester.java:9)
    at de.scrum_master.app.UpdateRequester.doSomething(UpdateRequester.java:5)
    at de.scrum_master.app.Test$1.run(Test.java:13)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Throwing message for request http://my.url.org/foo on page 'my page'
```

I.e. that `this()` is not `Test` but `Test$1` which is the anonymous inner `Runnable` subclass you define in your code. You also see that `Test.testUpdate()` is not really in the control flow as it is nowhere to be seen in the stack trace. You can modify the pointcut like this:

```java
pointcut testUpdateFlow() :
    cflow(
        this(Runnable) &&
        withincode(public void Test..*.run(..)) &&
        call(* UpdateRequester.*(..))
    );
```

It means: In the control flow of

- an instance of `Runnable`,
- somewhere within the code of a `public void run(..)` method defined below `Test` (inner class),
- calling any method of `UpdateRequester`.

I.e. now the aspect looks like this (the console output stays the same):

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

import de.scrum_master.app.UpdateRequester;
import java.lang.Runnable;

public aspect TestUpdate {
    pointcut testUpdateFlow() :
        cflow(
            this(Runnable) &&
            withincode(public void Test..*.run(..)) &&
            call(* UpdateRequester.*(..))
        );

    pointcut throwMessageCut(String url, String response) :
        this(UpdateRequester) &&
        args(url, response) &&
        execution(void throwMessage(String, String));

    before(String url, String response) :
        testUpdateFlow() &&
        throwMessageCut(url,  response)
    {
        System.out.println(thisJoinPoint);
        new Exception().printStackTrace(System.out);
    }
}
```

You could also use nested `cflow()` statements like this:

```java
pointcut testUpdateFlow() :
    cflow(
        this(Runnable) &&
        cflow(execution(public void Test..*.run(..))) &&
        call(* UpdateRequester.*(..))
    );
```

Alternatively, in order to avoid the anonymous inner class you can create a named inner class:

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class Test {
    public static class UpdateRequesterStarter implements Runnable {
        public void run() {
            new UpdateRequester().doSomething();
        }
    }

    public void testUpdate() {
        ScheduledExecutorService executorService = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(10);
        executorService.scheduleWithFixedDelay(
            new UpdateRequesterStarter(),
            500L,
            1000L,
            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS
        );
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test().testUpdate();
    }
}
```

Now the output changes, please note the difference in the call stack:

```
execution(void de.scrum_master.app.UpdateRequester.throwMessage(String, String))
java.lang.Exception
    at de.scrum_master.app.TestUpdate.ajc$before$de_scrum_master_app_TestUpdate$1$9c6f966b(TestUpdate.aj:24)
    at de.scrum_master.app.UpdateRequester.throwMessage(UpdateRequester.java:9)
    at de.scrum_master.app.UpdateRequester.doSomething(UpdateRequester.java:5)
    at de.scrum_master.app.Test$UpdateRequesterStarter.run(Test.java:10)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Throwing message for request http://my.url.org/foo on page 'my page'
```

Now you can refine/simplify the `testUpdateFlow()` pointcut to:

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

import de.scrum_master.app.UpdateRequester;
import de.scrum_master.app.Test.UpdateRequesterStarter;

public aspect TestUpdate {
    pointcut testUpdateFlow() :
        cflow(execution(public void UpdateRequesterStarter.run(..)));

    pointcut throwMessageCut(String url, String response) :
        this(UpdateRequester) &&
        args(url, response) &&
        execution(void throwMessage(String, String));

    before(String url, String response) :
        testUpdateFlow() &&
        throwMessageCut(url,  response)
    {
        System.out.println(thisJoinPoint);
        new Exception().printStackTrace(System.out);
    }
}
```

Please also note the changed `import` statements.

Comment: I didn't know about the syntax specifying "somewhere within the code of a public void run(..) method defined below Test (inner class)". Thanks a lot.